# Issues after .NET 4.5 Installation

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.5

I recently installed the newly released version of .NET 4.5 and have encountered nothing but trouble since the installation. My existing .NET 4.0 application appears to no longer work, with various errors / exceptions being thrown up. The current one being :

> There is no compatible TransportManager found for URI 'insert service
>   here'. This may be because you have used an absolute address that
>   points outside of the virtual application...

I attempted to remedy this though a suggestion that I had read regarding removing the address property of the services in the web.config, however this didn't alleviate any of the issues.

Are there any major problems that I may not be aware of that could cause my application to no longer run? Could there be issues with any WCF services that used previously? Or perhaps references that I may have to update in the existing application?

*(I apologize if the question is semi-vague, but I am not quite sure which direction I should start marching in to find a solution.)*

Comment: I doubt this will help, but I've also encountered problems w/ v4.5. If your v4.0 app includes extension methods and you've installed 4.5, your builds throw exceptions when run in a non upgraded v4.0 environment. After learning this, it doesn't surprise me there are other issues..

Comment: It's just a bizarre situation that it would cause this. If I create an application that runs on 4.5, it works just fine. However, I believe it has something to do with the WCF services that are running, as the solution builds without exception, however when it hits the service layer. Boom!

Comment: @RionWilliams Hello, Praburaj and I are from .NET Framework Team. We would like to take a look at your project to see what's going on. could you contact us on netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com with some repro code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem had to do with the WCF service endpoint mappings in the web.config. Primarily, those using "`mex`" endpoint addresses. I believe that our application had previously used these and when upgrading to 4.5, our existing workaround failed, as the problem itself had been solved.

Comment: Could you contact us on netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com to discuss? We want to reproduce this internally. At this point, we are unable to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Could you please be kind enough to elaborate a bit on what you did to fix the issue?